# how to parse this Xml type string

Tags: c#, xml, linq, string

Can some one guide me how to parse this Xml type string ?

```
<data>
  <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
  <AC1>12</AC1>
  <AC2>13</AC2>
  <AC3>14</AC3>
  <Moter></Moter>
  <Fan1></Fan1>
  <Fan2></Fan2>
  <TubeLight1></TubeLight1>
  <TubeLight2></TubeLight2>
  <Moter></Moter>
  <CloseAll></CloseAll>
</data>
```

I need to get all result in String or List or dictionary like
AC1=12 , AC2=13 and so on

Thnaks in advance

Comment: like with an `XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)`?

Comment: any thing =) i dont mind. i just wana parse that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work but you have to remove the duplicate `Moter` element from your XML - only then you can use a dictionary:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var dictionary = doc.Descendants("data")
                    .Elements()
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.ToString(), x => x.Value);
string ac1Value = dictionary["AC1"];
```

Comment: m geting Illegal characters in path. at line 'XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml);'

Comment: if you want to parse an *XML string* (and not a file) you have to use `XDocument.Parse(xmlString)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) method:

```
string data = @"<data>
                  <LastUpdate></LastUpdate>
                  <AC1>12</AC1>
                  <AC2>13</AC2>
                  <AC3>14</AC3>
                  <Moter></Moter>
                  <Fan1></Fan1>
                  <Fan2></Fan2>
                  <TubeLight1></TubeLight1>
                  <TubeLight2></TubeLight2>
                  <Moter></Moter>
                  <CloseAll></CloseAll>
            </data>";

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(data);

var parsedData = from obj in xmlDoc.Descendants("data")
                 select new
                 {
                     LastUpdate = obj.Element("LastUpdate").Value,
                     AC1 = obj.Element("AC1").Value,
                     AC2 = obj.Element("AC1").Value,
                     ... and so on
                 }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go for Linq to XML then it would look something like:

```
        XElement root = XElement.Parse(s);
        Dictionary<XName, string> dict = root
            .Elements()
            .Select(x => new {key = x.Name, value = x.Value})
            .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

Just make sure you deal with duplicates the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using XLinq. Here is the sample (in VB.NET):

```
 Private Sub ParseIt()

        Dim xml = XElement.Parse(sampleXml)

        Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        For Each item In xml.Elements
            dic.Add(item.Name.LocalName, item.Value)
        Next

    End Sub
```

Also you can use it like this (I prefer this method):

```
Private Sub ParseIt()

    Dim xml = XElement.Parse("")

    Dim dic = (From item In xml.Elements).ToDictionary(Function(obj) obj.Name.LocalName, Function(obj) obj.Value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse xml data string into  `'Dataset'` then you can use this sample

```
    string xmlString = @"/*.. .. .*/";

    DataSet data = new DataSet();

    data.ReadXml(new StringReader(xmlString));
```